# what does empty function name in go lang mean?

Tags: syntax, go

I am reading this code and I don't quite understand what line #2 does:

```
resp := route.Handler(req)
_, nilresponse := resp.(NilResponse)
if !nilresponse {

type NilResponse struct {
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an empty function name. This is a type-assertion. It is testing that `resp` is a `NilResponse`. If it is, then `nilResponse` will be true, otherwise it will be false. This code throws away the resulting type-asserted value by using `_`.

See [Type Assertions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

Answer (score 0):

If line two is `_, nilresponse := resp.(NilResponse)` then it's not a function call at all. It's a type assertion. The code is saying "the interface value represented by `resp` is of type `NilResponse`.

EDIT; your assignment is kind of odd though because the first return value would be the `NilResponse` object and the second (if specified) is a flag to indicate whether or not it worked (or maybe an error, can't remember if it's a bool or error). So typically it would be something like; `nilResponse, ok :=` or `nilResponse, err :=`